# Using Vuex State in main js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, state-management

I am trying to use my store state in main.js but it vanishes my component, can I use state in mian.js

```
Axios.defaults.headers.common['BranchId'] = this.$store.state.myBrachId,
```

if not what how can I set the default headers dynamically then..?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking how to access a Vuex store outside a Vue component. The syntax that you're currently using is only valid if you're writing a Vue component.

In case you want to access Vuex outside (any .js file) you should, first, export the store. Then, import that store in your file and finally use the store as you place.

Let's see an example:

*store/index.js*

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state () {
  myBrachId: 'niceBranch007'
 }
});
```

Then, in any other .js file (main.js in your case)

```js
import { store } from 'store/index.js'
console.log(store.state.myBrachId)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add headers to axios I'd ask you to consider if you should really be getting that header data from a Vuex store anyways.  Remember that any browser refresh will clear your store so you should not rely on it's availability more than you need to.  Using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` might be better for what you're looking to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this right now this is my store

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {

    branchId: "",
  },
  getters:{
  
  },
  mutations: {
    
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});
```

In header cmponent

```
this.$store.state.branchId = this.Branches[index].branchId;
```

in main js

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import { store } from './store/index'
Axios.defaults.headers.common['BranchId'] = store.state.branchId;
```

this is not setting axios header, it comes empty

Comment: Instead of pasting all of your code, you should only paste the part of the code that the asker of the questions needs.